# What is an alternative of textarea in react-native?

Tags: react-native

Is there any built in text area component for react-native? I have tried to implement these ones:

https://github.com/buildo/react-autosize-textarea

https://github.com/andreypopp/react-textarea-autosize

but getting an error "Expected a component class got object object".

Answer (score 224):

Yes there is. It's called TextInput, the normal TextInput Component supports multiple lines.

Just assign following properties to your TextInput Component

```
multiline = {true}
numberOfLines = {4}
```

At the end you should have this:

```
<TextInput
    multiline={true}
    numberOfLines={4}
    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
    value={this.state.text}/>
```

Source https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput

Answer (score 79):

If you want to see your `TextInput` component like a textarea, you will need to add this

```
<TextInput
    multiline={true}
    numberOfLines={10}
    style={{ height:200, textAlignVertical: 'top',}}/>
```

Comment: textAlignVertical: 'top' is the actual thing I was looking for thanks. 
this works really great

Comment: You help me with textAlignVertical: 'top'. Thank You

Comment: or you can directly use `textAlignVertical="top"` as a prop but that currently support only for android

Comment: upvote for "textAlignVertical"

Comment: nice save by textAlignVertical.!

Comment: What is the goal of `textAlignVertical: 'top'` here? It seems to work well without it

Comment: Thanks! `textAlignVertical: 'top'` helped me for Android. on iOS it works well without it.

Answer (score 40):

I build text areas in react-native by wrapping a `TextInput` component into a `View` the following way:

```
  <View style={styles.textAreaContainer} >
    <TextInput
      style={styles.textArea}
      underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
      placeholder="Type something"
      placeholderTextColor="grey"
      numberOfLines={10}
      multiline={true}
    />
  </View>
```

...

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  textAreaContainer: {
    borderColor: COLORS.grey20,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 5
  },
  textArea: {
    height: 150,
    justifyContent: "flex-start"
  }
})
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. super easy / simple to put together.

Comment: for some reason numberOfLines isn't doing anything for me. I'm not sure if this attribute is supposed to help in expanding the clickable area of the textInput or what exactly.

Comment: @Yokhen let's say that numberOfLines just allow you to type text in multiple lines when you combine it with "multiple" set to true (whose default value is false, so pay attention to this prop). On the other hand, the "textAreaContainer" and "textArea" styles that I added in the example above are useful to make the text input looks like a text area.

Comment: @NachoJusticiaRamos yeah I read that in the documentation, but numberOfLines does nothing in the iOS simulator at least. But I reckon this might be a question for another thread.

Comment: Slap in a `textAlignVertical: "top"` in `textArea: {...}` for good measure.

Comment: i'm looking for a text input like instagram with abilities like inline colored hashtags which ajax remote loadable under that line. I can't find anything useful.

Answer (score 7):

I am using this component: 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-autogrow-textinput

It expands automatically on-text growth. I created my own reusable component with the autogrow-textinput as part of it, which inside the component looks like that:

```
<AutoGrowingTextInput 
    minHeight={40}
    maxHeight={maxHeight} // this is a flexible value that I set in my 
        component, where I use this reusable component, same below, unless specified the other
    onChangeText={onChangeText}
    placeholder={placeholder}
    placeholderTextColor='#C7C7CD'
    style={inputStyle}
    value={value}
/>
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using only react-native components your option is `TextInput`

As "funkysoul" explained:

> Just assign following properties to your TextInput Component
>
> `multiline = {true}`
>   `numberOfLines = {4}`

If you want to see this component as the classic `textarea` (bigger than an inline text-input), you usually will need to add the `height` style-property. See the following example:

```
 <TextInput
     multiline={true}
     numberOfLines={10}
     style={{ height:200, backgroundColor:'red'}}
 />
```

I added the backgroundColor for a better understanding of the `height` role. Please don't use it on your project ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can make `textArea` in React Native like this:

```js
<View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: COLORS.white }}>

<TextInput 
    style={{
        flex:1,
        textAlignVertical:'top',
        justifyContent: "flex-start", 
        backgroundColor: 'white' 
    }} 
placeholder="type something here" 
multiline={true} 
/>

</View>
```